# Javascript - how to detect if there is document stored cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies

I used the following code to detect if the browser is enabling cookies, but it show errors when it come to extract cookies at the first time the page visited

```
if(!navigator.cookieEnabled){
alert("Please enable cookies on your web browser, to get a better experience with our website.");
} else {
var parameters=document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0;i<parameters.length;i++){
eval(parameters[i]);
}
}
```

the navigator shows the following error `Invalid left-hand side in assignment
    at library.js:212`

Comment: What's in `parameters` (what is stored in the cookies)? I'm willing to bet `eval(parameters[i]);` is the issue.

Comment: That's a very dangerous piece of code...

Comment: I've never seen `eval` used to read cookies before. Don't

Comment: i used the same cookies extraction lines `eval(parameters[i]);` in different pages, where they are already created in the home page and worked fine, but when i used it the home page, when users have first time visited the site, it doesn't work where parameters elements contains string in form of `variable=value`

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish by using `eval()`?